# Can't create a JTDS datasource in ColdFusion connecting to SQL2008

Tags: sql-server-2008, coldfusion, jtds, coldfusion-7

I am encountering an issue with a ColdFusion query executing in SQL2008 R2.  The query returns two rows when run through Management Studio but through ColdFusion it returns zero. On searching the web this points to the cache in ColdFusion, so I cleared that, no joy.  I even upgraded the ColdFusion driver for SQL, still no joy. Then I discovered JTDS on another forum but for the life of me I cannot get it to connect to my SQL Cluster.

Does anyone have a real world example of the JDBC URL (minus sensitive information) that they have succeeded in setting up? This is a connection to a named SQL instance running on a cluster.  Firewall is all ok, checked that and the normal ColdFusion SQL connection works fine.

I have tried (amongst many other combinations):

```
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP ADDRESS/Instance Name;database=DB Name
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP ADDRESS/Database Name;instance=Instance Name
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP ADDRESS:PORT/Instance Name;database=DB Name
jdbc:jtds:sqlserver://IP ADDRESS:POrt/Database Name;instance=Instance Name
```

SQL Instance is on port 59759 and allowed through the firewall.

I keep getting this error:

```
The root cause was that: java.sql.SQLException: 
Timed out trying to establish connection
```

I cannot upgrade ColdFusion at the moment.

Or if anyone knows why my query is failing, that would also be a help.

Comment: I have no issues connecting ColdFusion to SQL 2008 using the built-in Microsoft SQL Server drivers. Were you getting any errors with this setup?  One thing I will mention, I have had issues trying to connect to SQL named instances on ColdFusion 9.  Instead of using the named instance I specify the port number under the datasource and it works fine.